# how to split a monolith project in Sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

Is there a way to split up a monolith in SonarQube?  Several teams work in this monolith which makes it very difficult to see progress when all the code is together.  Is there a way to see several dashboard from the one project depending on packages/files that you choose?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to see a project home page for a module/package. Navigate to the desired level via the Code page, then click on the "link out" icon

[image]

However, if you want to be able to treat your components as truly independent entities, by for instance adding them to views, you'll need to analyze them independently.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I probably should've been more specific in my question.  The reason why I would want to do this is so that it can then be added to a view.  Could I then add this to an existing view?

Comment: See my expansion @CarlosMartini. It would be helpful to posterity if you would [edit] your question to include your expansion.